# Se deshabilita el el fomulario en php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un formulario que envía parámetros a una base de datos. Se trata de una ventana modal que al seleccionar una opción específica abre el formulario para la opción y con un id único de la misma.

Hasta aquí todo funcionaba bien, pero luego decidí añadir una barra de búsqueda para filtrar las opciones. Usé `AJAX` y `JavaScript` para que se ejecute la búsqueda en tiempo real, entonces aquí es cuando surge el problema.

El formulario, a pesar de que está correctamente codificado no funciona, creo que hace algún conflicto con la barra de búsqueda o con la consulta que hace la misma, no estoy seguro de que pueda ser.

Dejo los códigos...

```
function search() {
    var texto = document.getElementById("busqueda").value;
    var parametros = {
        "texto" : texto
    };

    $.ajax ({
        data: parametros,
        url : "../ajax/valida.php",
        type: "POST",
        success : function(response){
            $("#datos").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

```
<?php
    include ("php/conexion2.php");
    session_start();
    #error_reporting(0);

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null || $_SESSION["rol_id"] != 'Administrador'){
        print "<script>alert(\"Acceso inválido!\");window.location='index.php';</script>";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PANEL</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/toggle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/modal.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
        <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funcion.js"></script>
        <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    </head>
    <?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
    <body onload="search();">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="left-bar-pedidos" class="left-bar-pedidos">
        <div class="bar-sub-1" >
          <div class="bar-sub-1-1">
            <div style="width: 40px; height: 40px">
              <img src="images/user1.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bar-sub-name">
            <span style="font-size: 16px; color: #fff;"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['nick_id'];?></strong></span>
            <span style="font-size: 13px; color: #b6b6b6;"><?php echo $_SESSION['rol_id'];?></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="barra">
          <div class="search" style="height: 40px;">
            <input type=image src="images/search.png" width="20" height="20" style="position: absolute; left: 33px">
            <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar" value="" onkeyup="search();">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="board" >
            <div class="bar-sub-2">
            <div class="bar-sub-2-1">
              <hr>
              <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #b6b6b6; text-align: left;"><span>PEDIDOS</span></div>
            </div>
            <div id="datos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    include("../php/conexion2.php");
    $tmp = "";
    $sql="SELECT * from transferencias where status= 0";
    $texto = $_POST["texto"];
    if($texto =! "" ){
        $sql="SELECT * from transferencias Where
            (usernamesend LIKE '".$_POST["texto"]."%' AND status = '0') or
            (namesend LIKE '".$_POST["texto"]."%' AND status = '0') or
            (identifysend LIKE '".$_POST["texto"]."%' AND status = '0') or
            (identifytypesend LIKE '".$_POST["texto"]."%' AND status = '0') or
            (cuenta LIKE '".$_POST["texto"]."%' AND status = '0') or
            (bank LIKE '".$_POST["texto"]."%' AND status = '0') or
            (datesent LIKE '".$_POST["texto"]."%' AND status = '0')
        ";
    }
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        include ('../view_request.php');
    }
?>
```

**Aquí es donde está el formulario**

```
<div id="screen-pedido-id=<?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?>" class="screen-pedido">
  <a href="#close" title="Cerrar" class="close">
    <img class="close" src="./images/delete-icon.png" onmouseout="this.src='./images/delete-icon.png';" onmouseover="this.src='./images/delete-icon1.png';"/>
  </a>
  <div id="modal-title">
    <strong>DETALLES DEL PEDIDO NÚMERO <?php echo $mostrar['id']?></strong> 
  </div>
  <table class="transfermodal">
    <tr>
      <td>NOMBRE Y APELLIDO</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['namesend'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        CÉDULA
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="transfermodal" style="margin: 0px; width: 100%">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0;"><?php echo $mostrar['identifytypesend'] ?></td>
            <td style="width: 90%; padding-left: 0px;"><?php echo $mostrar['identifysend'] ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NÚMERO DE CUENTA</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['cuenta'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TIPO DE CUENTA</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['accountype'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BANCO</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['bank'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PESOS A ENVIAR</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['pesossend'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CAMBIO</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['tasasend'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL BS. A ENVIAR</td>
      <td><?php echo $mostrar['bssend'] ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="modal-obs">
    <strong>OBSERVACIONES</strong>
    <textarea readonly ><?php echo $mostrar['obs'] ?></textarea>  
  </div>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <div class="submit-modal">
    <div id="submit-modal-title">REFERENCIA</div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <form id="transferstatus" name="transferstatus" action="./php/trans_ref.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar['id']; ?>" method="post">
            <td style="width: 60%;">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ref" value="<?php if($mostrar['ref'] != 'Pendiente')echo $mostrar['ref'];?>" style="width: 100%;" required />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="ACTUALIZAR" style="width: 150px;">
            </td>
          </form>
        </tr>
      </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Ocupa la zona de network de los navegadores para saber qué mandas y a fuer de, saber qué te responde el servidor. 2. Genera los scripts haciendo un echo a tu variable $sql para pegarla en tu motor de base de datos y saber si ahí se encuentra el problema de acuerdo al paso 1. 3. Da más información sobre el anterior debuggeo para poderte ayudar.